# Is it possible to check if cookies are enabled with modernizr?

Tags: browser, cookies, modernizr

I was researching about how to check if the *cookies* are enabled in a browser and i found a lot of answer, i even tested a few ones, but after that a friend of mine suggest me to use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for that.
I started to search about that and i found a lot of stuff related with **CSS3** and **HTML5**, but i don't want that, i just wanna know if is it possible to check that *cookies* are enabled or not with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check this url, hope it's helpful :

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/commit/33f00fbbeb12e92bf24711ea386e722cce6f60cc

Answer (score 8):

Below code is copied from http://sveinbjorn.org/cookiecheck.

```
function are_cookies_enabled()
{
    var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled)
    { 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled);
}
```

Comment: Related with this, which one of these two solutions will be better in terms of performance?

Comment: Well, the javascript only method outlined above is about as lightweight as it gets.

Comment: be careful with this... `navigator.cookieEnabled` always returns `true` in IE9

Answer (score 6):

A direct answer to the question is 'Yes!' and it is built in

Example code:

```
if (Modernizr.cookies == false) {

    alert('Please enable cookies');    
}
else { 
    // do something with cookies
}
```

You can also use the css class `.cookies` or `.no-cookies` to show/hide a panel telling the user they need cookies enabled.

```
.cookies #noCookies
{
    display: none;
}

<div id='#noCookies'>
   This site requires cookies! Please turn them on already!
</div>
```

(This `.cookies` class is added to `<body>` tag by Modernizr).

Note: If you are creating a custom build of Modernizr the `cookies` option is currently 'hidden' under the 'Non-core detects' section.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with PHP

HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['cook'] = 1;
  echo "<img src=\"cookcheck.php\">";
?>
```

PHP - cookcheck.php:

```
 <?php
     session_start();

     if ($_SESSION['cook'] !== 1) 
                             { $image="/nocookmsg.png"; }    # Cookies NOT Enabled
                               else { $image="/blank.png"; } # Cookies Enabled

     $img=imageCreateFromPNG($image);   # Create Image
     header("Content-type: image/png"); # Send Header
     imagePNG($image);                  # Send Image
 ?>
```