# navigator.cookieEnabled not working in IE9 in localhost

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, localhost

I am working with asp.net, and in my logon.aspx page I have the following code copied from a previous question/answer:
[is it possible to check if cookies are enabled with modernizr ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130457/is-it-possible-to-check-if-cookies-are-enabled-with-modernizr)

```
function are_cookies_enabled() {
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = "testcookie";
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
        }
        return (cookieEnabled);
    }
```

But when I run my local server (the Visual Studio 2010 integrated one), the variable cookieEnabled is always false, but it is only happening in my localhost, when I tried the same code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it works perfectly. (the above code works for all the browsers except in IE9, in localhost)
Any idea??

Comment: Maybe `localhost` is in the wrong browser security zone?

Comment: i tested the same code with the same browser but not in localhost, instead i tested it in a dev server and it works, any explanation for that??? (now i am testing to set localhost in a trusted zone)

Comment: i recently checked and i have in the managed websites the localhost(127.0.0.1) with always allow setting in the privacy settings of the IE9

Answer (score 3):

Try

option 1: `http://127.0.0.1 /`  instead of `http://localhost:5130/` ie; just disabling cookie on your browser will only set internet settings

So give IP adress -> Start-> Run->Cmd->Type ipconfig then you will see your IP adresses shown below

option 2

```
http://IPADRESS/app/urpag.aspx
```

then check with below javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("Cookies enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to lock out my previously working IE9 so that if security zone is *Local Intranet*, it will report:

> navigator.cookieEnabled == false

If I change the zone to *Internet* and *protected mode* on, the cookies are enabled. Before this happened, I did change the privacy settings. I have no idea how to get it back. Perhaps a re-install would help.