# navigator.cookieenabled not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have disabled my IE cookie. When I am trying to login with my Hotmail account in IE it is showing "Your browser is currently set to block cookies. Your browser must allow cookies before you can use a Microsoft account."
But in my code `navigator.cookieEnable` is always return true.

It is working in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is my JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!navigator.cookieEnabled)
    {
        alert("Please enable cookies in your browser settings to continue.");
    }    
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this on localhost? There are several questions regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9364279/215552 is one of them.

Comment: Yes. But the same code on QA server is not working.