# Modernizr and Storage Detection

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I know I can detect if a browser supports local storage as follows:

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
  // Local storage available
} else {
  // No local storage
}
```

If Modernizr detects there is no local storage support, does that automatically mean, across most browsers, that session storage is also not available and cookies are not as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly: no.

It simply means you don't have `window.localStorage` *interface* in the browser. sessionStorage has it's own flag.

source: http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5

Comment: What about cookies? I don't see cookies even mentioned on that page.

Comment: It looks like they have a test for that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130457/is-it-possible-to-check-if-cookies-are-enabled-with-modernizr

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between cookies & localstorage is that cookies have expiration date (even if it's far in the future), but entries of localstorage don't.
localstorage is an HTML-5 thing. So, there're plenty of legacy browsers that have support of cookies (of course), but don't support localstorage (like IE6,7 and others).

I think among these 3 things, cookies have the broadest support.